# adding List Elements

Tags: python, list

My final list is like this...

```
lst = ['Ram:50', 'Ram:80', 'Ram:90', 'Ram:20', 'Sam:40', 'Sam:70', 'Sam:80']
```

How to separate all Ram into one list and all Sam in to another list from Python.

Example:

```
[50,80,90,20]
[40,70,80]
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's quite straightforward: [Iterate over the list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), [split the string](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), add value to corresponding list. What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = ['Ram:50', 'Ram:80', 'Ram:90','Ram:20', 'Sam:40', 'Sam:70', 'Sam:80']
>>> [int(x[4:]) for x in l if x.startswith('Ram:')]
[50, 80, 90, 20]
>>> [int(x[4:]) for x in l if x.startswith('Sam:')]
[40, 70, 80]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lis = ['Ram:50', 'Ram:80', 'Ram:90','Ram:20', 'Sam:40', 'Sam:70', 'Sam:80']
>>> D = {'Ram':[], 'Sam':[]}
>>> for k,v in (x.partition(':')[::2] for x in lis):
...    D[k].append(v)
... 
>>> D['Ram']
['50', '80', '90', '20']
>>> D['Sam']
['40', '70', '80']
```

Slightly more advanced is to initialise D like this

```
D = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: An answer that **wont** need fundamental changes if the names were 'Ramu' and 'Sam'.

Comment: Why use `partition` over `split`?

Comment: @jamylak, partition won't fail if the delimiter is not present. Usually it is slightly faster than split

Answer (score 1):

```
([int(x[4:]) for x in l if x[:3] == 'Ram'],
 [int(x[4:]) for x in l if x[:3] == 'Sam'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ram = map(lambda y: int(y[y.find(":")+1:]), filter(lambda x: x[:x.find(":")] == "Ram", lst))
```

I see just now root45's solution is similar, but much easier.

Back one day later to summarize common wisdom:

```
for name in ('Ram', 'Sam'):
    globals()[name] = [int(x[x.find(":")+1:]) for x in lst if x[:x.find(":")] == name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done using regex and list comprehensions -

```
>>> list = ['Ram:50', 'Ram:80', 'Ram:90', 'Ram:20', 'Sam:40', 'Sam:70', 'Sam:80']
>>> [re.findall(r'[0-9]*$',s)[0] for s in list if 'Ram' in s]
['50', '80', '90', '20']
>>> [re.findall(r'[0-9]*$',s)[0] for s in list if 'Sam' in s]
['40', '70', '80']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a robust solution.

The first phase converts the input list into a list of tuples of `[(key,value),(key,value)...]` form. The `map` operation does this transformation using the split function here.

```
l = ['Ram:50', 'Ram:80', 'Ram:90', 'Ram:20', 'Sam:40', 'Sam:70', 'Sam:80']

def split( input ):
    sp = input.split(":")
    return (sp[0], sp[1])
l2 = map(split, l)
print l2

#[('Ram', '50'), ('Ram', '80'), ('Ram', '90'), ('Ram', '20'), ('Sam', '40'), ('Sam', '70'), ('Sam', '80')]
```

The second phase iterates over such a list and populates the `store` dict. If the key doesnt exist, it creates a list (of one element) that maps to the key. Else it adds to that list

```
store = {}
for i in l2:
    key, value = i[0], i[1] 
    if key not in store.keys():
        store[key] = [value]
    else:
        store[key].append(value)

print store
#{'Ram': ['50', '80', '90', '20'], 'Sam': ['40', '70', '80']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is already ordered by `'ram'` then `'sam'` you can do this

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = ['Ram:50', 'Ram:80', 'Ram:90', 'Ram:20', 'Sam:40', 'Sam:70', 'Sam:80']
>>> [[int(y) for x,y in v] for k,v in groupby((el.split(':') for el in lst),itemgetter(0))]
[[50, 80, 90, 20], [40, 70, 80]]
```